# NodeJS v12 re-enable TLS 1.1, and 1.0

Tags: node.js, node-modules, tls1.2, tls1.0, tls1.1

Node now supports TLS 1.3 which offers increased security and reduced latency.

By implementing TLS 1.3, Node apps will have increased end-user privacy while also improving the performance of requests by reducing the time required for the HTTPS handshake.

TLS 1.0 and 1.1 have been disabled by default, and the crypto library has removed deprecated functions.

Is there a way to re-enable 1.0, and 1.1 in anyway?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution: Run Node with the `--tls-min-v1.0` command line argument.

Reference: [GitHub issue #27384: --tls-v1.0 flag doesn't work on Node v12](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27384).